# How to create a branch on a existing folder in AzureDevops in visual studio?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I am working with Source Control Explorer inside Visual Studio, and I am very confused with the way it works:

I have a project, where the structure is:

Folder

- Branch

  - Folder

As in:
[image]

I just tried creating one myself (I never created one myself) and I can't ge the same structure... How can I create a branch so I match the above structure??
[image]

The only documentation I found is only related to Git in Visual Studio and not to this Azure DevOps-like.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are using the TFVC Repo and there is a plus sign in front of your folders. This means that the changes hasn't been checkin to the TFVC repo server side.

To match the above structure, you need to checkin the change first.

[image]

Then you can right click on the folder and select **Branching and Merging -> Branch**.

[image]